# Recover backend information in working remotely with the IBM-QC

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I'm reading the details of `qiskit` following [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03452.pdf) (I know it's a little bit dated, but some things shown there should be in principle still accessible). For concreteness I'm trying to see the characteristics of the backend

```
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q')
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_quito')
```

Now, according to the reference, the backend have to be equipped with the configuration files. However, if I do

```
backend.configuration()
```

I only get

```
<qiskit.providers.models.backendconfiguration.QasmBackendConfiguration object at 0x7f5f567af760>
```

How can I display the full information for this backend, e.g. backend_name, backend_version, etc. etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want, everything is detailed [here](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/manage/systems/configuration#system-configuration) about the system configuration, it will explain everything you can find in the configuration.

Just a quick resume about how to see the info : personally, I sometimes use `backend.configuration().to_dict()`, with this all of the information will be printed in a `dict`, and it's pretty easy to use. Now, you can also do a "pretty" print of this by using the [Jupiter tools](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/tools_jupyter.html) (there's a lot of useful stuffs here other than printing backend config just in case), anyway by doing this :

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
import qiskit.tools.jupyter
%matplotlib inline

IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q')
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_quito')
backend
```

This will give you a pretty print of the backend configuration :)